# Assign a name to unnamed columns in a Pandas DataFrame with multiindex

Tags: python-3.x

I ran the below python script:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Security Issuer', header=[0, 1, 2],
                   skiprows=7, nrows=None, usecols=None, index_col=None,
                   index=False, engine='openpyxl')
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Output:

```sh
       Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0                Yield
       Unnamed: 1_level_1  Unnamed: 2_level_1                Total
             Country         Issuer           Unnamed: 3_level_2
0                UK           UK Govt                     1.2
1                US           US Govt                     1.5
2                EU           EU Govt                     8.3
```

I want to name all the unnamed columns, so I tried the following code:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.values
    
df = df.rename(columns={
    ('Unnamed: 1_level_0', 'Unnamed: 1_level_1'): ('Country', 'Country'),
    ('Unnamed: 2_level_0', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1'): ('Issuer', 'Issuer'),
    ('Unnamed: 3_level_0'): ('Total')
})

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

The output is the same as before:

```sh
       Unnamed: 1_level_0  Unnamed: 2_level_0                Yield
       Unnamed: 1_level_1  Unnamed: 2_level_1                Total
             Country         Issuer           Unnamed: 3_level_2
0                UK           UK Govt                     1.2
1                US           US Govt                     1.5
2                EU           EU Govt                     8.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use the multilevel? You could try:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
# Rename
df.columns = ['column1','column2']
# Or
df = df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})
```

Comment: I actually need the multilevel because the complete data set is multilevel to create unique names for each column